# $C^{\infty}$ path-connected

Tags: real-analysis

We know that:

If $G\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is open  and connected then $G$  is polygonally path-connected (with sides parallel to the coordinate axes).

> But if $G\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is open  and connected then $G$  is  $C^{1}$path-connected ?
>
> is  $C^{\infty}$path-connected ?

Any hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

It is $C^{\infty}$ path connected. After your polygon-path is constructed the only "bad" points are the vertices of the path. Now choose a small ball around the vertex. All you need to do is construct a $C^{\infty}$ path inside the ball, that connects to a given two points $C^{\infty}$ smoothly. This can be done (for the formula use a cube not a ball. then you can construct your function coordinate-vise because all you need is $C^{\infty}$ function that connects to linear functions)